How do I find purely-real expressions for the absolute value of this complex function?
I am working on a project that involves the squares of the absolute values of some two-real-input-variable complex functions, and I want to find purely-real expressions for those absolute values in terms of the two input variables.
As an example, I have the function
$$
g_{07}(R, φ) = \frac{\sqrt{2} ⋅ e^{\left(i ⋅ \frac{2 π}{3} ⋅ 1\right)} - R ⋅ (\cos(φ) + i ⋅ \sin(φ))}{\sqrt{2} ⋅ R ⋅ (\cos(φ) + i ⋅ \sin(φ)) ⋅ e^{\left(i ⋅ \frac{2 π}{3} ⋅ 2\right)} + 1}
$$
and I want to find $|g_{07}(R, φ)|^2$.
By having a computer evaluate it, I know the result has zero imaginary component, but I'm not sure how to go about finding an explicit expression for it that eliminates $i$. Knowing that $|z|^2 = z ⋅ \overline{z}$, I tried flipping the signs of the imaginary terms and multiplying that with the original function, but while the resulting expression is purely real, it is not equal to $|g_{07}(R, φ)|^2$. When I also negated the exponents of the exponential terms and multiplied that with the original, the $φ$ variable canceled out completely, which isn't what I need either.

your expression is of the form $g=\frac{ae^{i\alpha}-Re^{i\phi}}{aRe^{i\phi}e^{i\beta}+1}$. If $R$, $a$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\phi$ are real, then $|g|^2=\frac{a^2+R^2-2aR\cos(\phi-\alpha)}{a^2R^2+1+2aR\cos(\phi+\beta)}$

@Sal I verified that your equation works for the function I used as an example. Can you explain how you derived it so I can find similar equations for other functions that don't have the exact same form?

I just multiplied by $\bar{g}=\frac{ae^{-i\alpha}-Re^{-i\phi}}{aRe^{-i\phi}e^{-i\beta}+1}$, expanded out all the terms, and used $2\cos (z)=e^{iz}+e^{-iz}$ to simplify a bit
